# Adjusting Height of Panel Columns using CSS

Tags: theming, panels

I am using panel-2col-brick to make a 2 x 2 information block. The HTML structure of the page is as follows

```
<div class="panel-display panel-2col-bricks clearfix">
  <div class="panel-panel panel-col-top">
  <div class="center-wrapper">
      <div class="panel-panel panel-col-first"></div>
      <div class="panel-panel panel-col-last"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-panel panel-col-middle">
  <div class="center-wrapper">
      <div class="panel-panel panel-col-first"></div>
      <div class="panel-panel panel-col-last"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i need to change height of the second occurrence of panel-col-first and panel col-second. I have tried

```
.panel-2col-bricks .center-wrapper .panel-col-first:first-of-type,
.panel-2col-bricks .center-wrapper .panel-col-last:first-of-type{
       height:80px;
       overflow:hidden;
}
```

However this changes  the height of both top-first and bottom-first columns. Is there any way i can adjust height of both rows separately ?

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this you need make use of CSS pseudo selectors and apply them in the correct element, a good approach can be this:

```
.panel-2col-bricks > .panel-panel:nth-child(2) .center-wrapper .panel-col-first,
.panel-2col-bricks > .panel-panel:nth-child(2) .center-wrapper .panel-col-last
```

You can see this in action in the link below:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBZGGb

Comment: If this answer is correct for your problem please mark this as accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Jjsg08. I tried it, but unfortunately it did not work. This CSS portion has stopped applying altogether with the mentioned changes.

Comment: Also panel-panel and center-wrapper are at the same level. They do not share parent child relationship. so i tried 

.panel-display .center-wrapper:nth-child(2) .panel-panel{
 height:80px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

However this only changes the first row. Whereas it is supposed to apply to second row of columns

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Jjsg08's idea of CSS pseudo selectors i was able to figure it out. The idea is to jump in multiples of 2. So `.center-wrapper:nth-child(2)` will apply to first row whereas `.center-wrapper:nth-child(4)` will apply to second. Strange as it may seem, as i have only **two** center-wrapper elements in the code, it works.